# How to find the distance between layer feature and point?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, distance, layer

Why won't the following code work?

```
   function showResult() {

      var pointA = new OpenLayers.LonLat(arxikoLon, arxikoLat).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
      var minDistance = stationsMarkersLayer1a.features[0].geometry.distanceTo(pointA, {details: false, edge: true});
var index =0;
      for (var i = 1; i <= stationsMarkersLayer1a.features.length - 1; i++) {
         var dist = stationsMarkersLayer1a.features[i].geometry.distanceTo(pointA, {details: false, edge: true});
         if (dist < minDistance) {
            index = i;
            minDistance = dist; 
         }
     }
  }
```

stationsMarkersLayer is the layer and arxikoLon and arxikoLat are variables globally declared in the above code! Ask for more details!

When I comment all of the above code and wirte another function instead like this one:

```
   function showResult() { 
   document.getElementById('resultStasi').innerHTML = stationsMarkersLayer1a.features[0].attributes['description'];
   document.getElementById('resultDromologio').innerHTML = arxikoLat;
    }
```

the results for innerHTML are just fine

Comment: It isn't very easy to know without knowing the values of arxikoLon, arxikoLat, stationsMarkersLayer1a.features and some expected value for the distance. Knowing fromProjection and toProjection would also be helpful.

Comment: arxikoLon and arxikoLat are lon and lat taken from an onclick function,stationsmarkersLayer1a is a layers that consists of geometry points that have been added to the layer as features,from projection to projection are the variables used to change the lat and lon units in order to have the right projection! anything else? please help I am desperate!

Comment: OK, so fromProjection is 4326. What is toProjection? Could you give a couple of example points from stationsMarkers, a couple a lat/lon in your area, and more or less what you expect the distance to be. That will be enough.

Comment: sorry john for the inconvenience but I am really new to this kind of stuff and I need to build it soon for my professor,and thanks beforehand for the energy you put in. fromProjection is 4326 and toProjection  is 900913,which is called i think Spherical Mercator Projection. LonLat i use in my area is like 22.9459, 39.3609, and I think the problem is when I declare var minDistance. At that point and afterwards it breaks.Whatver you need just let me know!

Comment: And an example of stationsMarkersLayer1a.features[i].geometry? Any one will do.

Comment: just to be clear, when you say it doesn't work, you mean you don't get a distance, or you get some other error?

Comment: the button wont work at all.If I can get it to work then I will try to see what happens with the distance.

An example from the stationsMarkersLayer1a is this


stationsMarkersLayer1a = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");
new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(22.96336,39.35071).transform(fromProjection, toProjection),
    {description:'Αφετηρία Άναυρος'} ,
    {externalGraphic: 'redMarker.png', graphicHeight: 25, graphicWidth: 21, graphicXOffset:-12, graphicYOffset:-25  }
        );
stationsMarkersLayer1a.addFeatures(stationMarkers_1a);

Comment: Do you have any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @JohnBarça I also edited the problem above I added another function instead of mine and the button works just fine. I think I have a problem at the distanceTo line!!

Comment: Ok,if javascript console is the one you get at your browser I get two errors one for a layer that I dont use in this part of my code and another 5 for the openlayers api which i dont think that i can do something for.I fixed it just in case,and it still wont work.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure I can help more without a full example, there are too many unknowns. Can you create a jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: @JohnBarça friend I tried to work with jsfidle but i cant get it to work because I have an external js file and i cant get tit to work. if there is anything I can give you tell me.Could it be the fromproj,toproj that is bad? should I have my coordinates turned to 4326? Do you know any good examples online where i can find distance from feature to point??

Comment: You can try 4326, seeing as all your coordinates appear to be in lat/lon. Generally you use reprojection to convert vector features for display on wms tiles that are in something like 3857/900913. So, if you are just doing distance from something in 4326 to something else in 4326, then just use 4326, or convert both to 3857.

Comment: @JohnBarça Just in case that affects anything, I am using :
map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap");
mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();

Comment: I will try your code snippet later. I can't promise anything, as you say there are errors elsewhere.